# How do I run a php filter against each array item, keeping the items that pass in the array?

Tags: php, filter

I have an array of values I want to run php's built-in email validation filter on. How do I run the filter against each array item, keeping the items that pass in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php's `array_filter`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Example (Updated to use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL):

```
function validate_email($email_address)
{
   return filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

$email_addresses = array("me@example.com", "123");

$email_addresses = array_filter($email_addresses, "validate_email");
```

Now, $email_addresses will only contain me@example.com

Comment: So can I use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL as the callback function?

Comment: You can use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL in your callback function. See the updated example.

Comment: If you're using 5.3 or above you need not define the callback beforehand, you can use a lamda function.